# What benefit does MSDN article on CoRevokeClassObject talk about?

Tags: windows, winapi, com

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688650(VS.85).aspx) on CoRevokeGetClassObject() says that when the COM server calls it the class object referenced by clients is not released. Then the following comes:

> If other clients still have pointers to the class object and have caused the reference >count to be incremented by calls to IUnknown::AddRef, the reference count will not be >zero. When this occurs, applications may benefit if subsequent calls (with the obvious >exceptions of IUnknown::AddRef and IUnknown::Release) to the class object fail.

What is meant by "applications may benefit"? The class object is not released, but creation requests fail. Sounds reasonable but where's the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a pretty strange turn of words...

I think what they're trying to say is that clients may end up in a tricky situation if they create objects from a server that just called `CoRevokeClassObjects`, because it's likely it'll disappear very soon (`CoRevokeClassObjects` is routinely called when a server is shut down.)

So, if the activation calls (`IClassFactory::CreateInstance`) don't fail, the client will get an interface pointer back, and as soon as they call a method on it, they'll get an error from the RPC layer that the server is gone.

I suppose that's 'beneficial' in some way :-)

That said, I'm not sure how to detect the case where `IUnknown::Release` is called via `CoRevokeClassObjects` vs some other client, but I suppose the code revoking the factories could set some global state or per-factory state that they can check before letting creation requests come through.